# I have mistake in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to compare date entering from a combobox as string with the date that saved into SQL Server database,then summation some values X but comparison doesn't work ...

```
string from = (comboBox4.Text+ '/' + comboBox5.Text + '/' + comboBox6.Text+ " 00:00:00 AM");
string to = (comboBox1.Text+ '/' + comboBox2.Text + '/' + comboBox3.Text);    

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from issued where issued.Date >='" +from + " ' And issued.Date < '" + to + " ' "; //مقارنة الاسم
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {
       item = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
       item.SubItems.Add(dr[4].ToString());
       f6.listView1.Items.Add(item);
       x += Convert.ToInt16(dr[4]);
   }
}
```

Help me please..

Comment: lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: `issued.Date` should be just `Date` I believe, since you're not dealing with several tables in one SQL-query.

Comment: When you say `but comparison doesn't work`, what is happening that should not happen?  Are you getting too many records?  No records?

Comment: @DanielLisik I believe that's valid syntax.  You can use the name of a table as a prefix, just as if it were an alias.  (Assuming this is SQL Server.)

Comment: i have 6 records provide the condition,when the debuging arrive to first if statement directly exite from it and make the value of X equal 0 .

Comment: The way the first two lines are formatted I wondered at first whether this is actually C# or not.

Comment: @DanielLisik there is absolutely nothing wrong with prefixing a column name in a single table query.

Answer (score 2):

As Marc stated above, you really should be careful of sql injection attacks here. Look it up and do some research because you'll suddenly find you have a compromised server someday.

Is your Date column of type Date or DateTime? If it's DateTime, then simply comparing on a specific date does not include that date for the upper bound. For instance, if your dates are:

From: 1/1/2013
To: 1/1/2014

Then your comparison would not return any values from 1/1/2014, and the last date included in the search would actually be 12/31/2013.

Add a little more specifics to your question regarding what values you are actually sending in your sql and what the types are in your db and you'll get a better answer!

Good luck!

Comment: Dear friends
Thank you very much i'm find the solution of the mistake :

Comment: by exchanging convert.toint16  by int.parse